# Playwright Locator Issue

Tags: python, automation, playwright, playwright-python

I am using Playwright trying to automate a button clicking action. I have tried to locate the HTML content through several methods, but will not click and proceed to the next screen.

Here is the HTML content:

```html
[<button class="c-button checkoutConfirmButton--OXR5TyUP f-primary f-flex" data-bi-dnt="true" data-tv-strategy-up="projection" data-focus-rank="0">Checkout</button>]
```

Methods used so far:

```js
page.get_by_role("button", name="Checkout").click()
page.get_by_text("Checkout", exact=True).click()
page.get_by_role("button", name="Checkout").click()
```

I expect the page to move to the next screen but the code refuses to interact. I've also added many print statements for errors and found out the button is not being located. Am I messing up my "locators" or should I use something else?

Note: This is the only content with "Checkout" on the page.

Comment: Would it be possible to share the site and a [mcve]? Thanks.

Comment: @ggorlen 
First, go to "https://www.xbox.com/en-US/consoles/xbox-series-x/diablo-iv-bundle#purchase"; then, choose a random bonus game and go to checkout. There, the "checkout" button with the same exact html element will show after inspecting. 

My methods so far:
page.locator("button", has_text="Checkout").click()
page.get_by_text("Checkout", exact=True).click()
page.get_by_role("button", name="Checkout").click()

I've added a wait time and a print statement to notify me if it was page-loading issues or to see if the button has been located; I found out that 10s was sufficient.

Comment: Thanks, but that's a bit hard to follow in a comment. Can you [edit] that into the post?

Comment: @ggorlen
For sure, sorry about the terrible appearance.

Comment: That checkout button is in an iframe. Are you using a [frame locator](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-framelocator) to select the frame?

Comment: @ggorlen

An iframe? Sorry, I have basic HTML knowledge but will look into the documentation. Thanks for pointing out the possible issue. I'll get back to you if there are any issues.

Comment: @ggorlen

Thank you so much. I was going insane over the fact that I was able to navigate pages perfectly but couldn't click the button for the life of me. Thanks to this community too. Since I have basic HTML knowledge, I had no clue what an iframe was nor how it could affect the program.